# Creating a monitor in Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, unity-game-engine

I have a prefab of a submarine I made in blender. In this submarine there is a "altitude" screen which is basically a cube I scaled and painted black.
I can easly get the altitude of my submarine by doing sub.transform.position.y.
Now I want to put a "Text" over the screen with the altitude I am getting.

My question is : What is the best way to do it ?

In an Ideal world I would have a function like
`TextObject putTextOnTop(GameObject the_panel)`
that would generate a textObject that I would then update each frame with my value.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple solutions for this.

There is an old 3D Text component in unity. This can do what you want. The Problem with this is, that you have only limited styling options.

A Better way is to use a WorldSpaceCanvas.
If you use this option, you have all TextMeshPro styling options.

Here is a video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GuWEXBeHEy8

The video is not very good, but i can't find a better one.

If you have any Questions left, feel free to ask

Comment: Thank you this looks promising, I didn't knew you could make canvas in world space, I'll look into that

Answer (score 1):

You can put the **Text GameObject** to be the child of the screen **(Cube GameObject)**, there are 2 ways for this:

1. Set directly in **Hierarchy**
2. Create a prefab **TextObject** and save it in Resources with path: `Resources/UI/TextObject`. Then in the code, instance and add it as a child of the **Cube** using the following code:

   ```
   GameObject textObject = Instantiate(Resources.Load("/UI/TextObject") as GameObject);

   textObject.transform.SetParent(cube.transform, false);
   ```

Then, in the Update function you add the following code:

```
void Update()
{
    TextObject.GetComponent<Text>().text =  sub.transform.position.y.ToString();
}
```

Hope it can help you!

Comment: I didn't though about using prefabs, I'll look into that, do you have an exemple of "TextObject" that would work great in this case ? I am working with TextMeshPro but maybe there are better alternatives ?